# Is it possible to host the SSRS Web portal on a separate machine from the SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, web, reporting-services

As the title says, I am setting up SSRS for my SQL, but I would like to have the Web Portal hosted on a different machine.
This is done because the SQL Server is in a domain that cannot be exposed to the internet and we have a requirement to expose the SSRS Web portal to the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, although the separate server has to be licensed separately. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15#creating-a-database-on-a-different-server  Also this is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Hi @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, the link only specified having a different database server for the reporting database. I was asking for the possibility of hosting the web components of SSRS on a different server (SSRS Web portal and SSRS Web Service). Thank you.

Comment: SSRS Web portal, SSRS Web Service, and the Databases.  That's all there is to SSRS.  You simply install SSRS on the web server and use the Report Server Configuration manager to create the databases on the other SQL Server.  Or you could use something like and Azure AD Application proxy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy  This article is for PBIRS, but would apply to SSRS too. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-integrate-with-power-bi